# Elementor add_control get data-id

Tags: wordpress, widget

I created a custom elementor widget. I want to get the data-id in the render() function every time a new widget is created.
How can I achieve this?

Here is the code for the render function :

```
protected function render() {
    global $wp_query;
    global $post;
    $this->print_unescaped_setting( 'custom_html' );
    $settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();

    $str = $settings['custom_php'];
    eval("$str");
    if(! empty ($settings['custom_function_php'] ) ){
        $str_php = $settings['custom_function_php'];
        //Get data-id
        $namepage = 'phpFile-' . get_the_ID() . '.php';
        $this->creat_file( $namepage, $str_php);
        require_once ( __DIR__ . '/' . $namepage );
    }   
}
```

Comment: you can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70356803/elementor-add-control-generate-unique-id/75162651#75162651)

Answer (score 3):

Inside the render() function you can call the **get_id()** method, for example i use it for this:

```
$map_id = 'map' . $this->get_id();
echo '<div id="' . $map_id . '"> here my Leaflet map </div>' ;
```

output

```
<div id="map88efa82"> here my Leaflet map </div>
```

get_id() is used in other interesting methods that you can call, watch inside the file here: elementor/includes/base/element-base.php

This is rendering the class name...

```
public function get_unique_selector() {
    return '.elementor-element-' . $this->get_id();
}
```

This is where they write the **data-id**...

```
protected function _add_render_attributes() {
    $id = $this->get_id();

    $this->add_render_attribute( '_wrapper', 'data-id', $id );
```

...and this returns an array with various data to analyze...

```
public function get_raw_data( $with_html_content = false ) {
    $data = $this->get_data();

    $elements = [];

    foreach ( $this->get_children() as $child ) {
        $elements[] = $child->get_raw_data( $with_html_content );
    }

    return [
        'id' => $this->get_id(),
        'elType' => $data['elType'],
        'settings' => $data['settings'],
        'elements' => $elements,
        'isInner' => $data['isInner'],
    ];
}
```